# NSNumberFormatter equivalence to stringWithFormat

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to convert doubles to strings with automatically(!) switching from from decimal to scientific if a given number of significant digits is reached (similar to stringWithFormat(".5g")!).
Examples:

```
55555 -> "55555"
55555.55 -> "55556"
555555.55 -> "5.5556E+05"
```

I can't figure out how to do that with "NSNumberFormatter().stringFromNumber"?

Can you help me?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. What does `NSNumberFormatterStyle.ScientificStyle` do? Does that always use scientific notation?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, so far (does anybody know better?):

```
extension NSNumberFormatter {
    func autoStringFromNumber (number: Double) -> String? {
        if abs(number) >= Double(10.power(maximumSignificantDigits)) {
            self.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.ScientificStyle
        }else{
            self.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
        }
        return self.stringFromNumber(number)
    }
}
```